# Dynamically load fonts in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, asynchronous, silverlight-4.0

I have the following (*list of fonts is actually much shorter for the purpose of this post*):

```
private static ObservableCollection<FontFamily> colFontFamilies = new ObservableCollection<FontFamily>()
{
     new FontFamily("/PrintVites;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Trajan Pro"),
     new FontFamily("/PrintVites;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Futura Std Light"),
     new FontFamily("/PrintVites;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#GeosansLight")
};
```

These are currently embedded fonts. How can I use the WebClient object to load these asynchronously after the application loads? Do I have to put them in a zip file, or can I load each font file separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out on my own by placing the fonts in a zip file and reading them in using the WebClient object.